# How to track changes to the model for the ui-scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

Specifically for javascipt
I dont know how to do it.
I have $scope.models , that I deduce the screen.
Method `get:` give me array-data from server

```
$scope.models = {
        get: function (index, count, success)
        {
            filterModel.Enddt = $scope.filter.enddt.toISOString();
            filterModel.Startdt = $scope.filter.startdt.toISOString();
            filterModel.Take = $scope.filter.nodeCount.count;
            filterModel.Type = $scope.filter.chooseView.value;
            filterService.getElectricityData(filterModel).then(function (data) {
                var results = [];
                var start = Math.max(0, index);
                var end = Math.min(index + count, data.length);
                for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    results.push(data[i]);
                }
                success(results);
            });
        }
    };
```

I think so to need create method `reload()` or `revision()`, that is deprecated.
Don't send me documentation from github, that is for coffee script.
And don't send me converter coffee to js:)
Please help me :C

Comment: `reload()` doesn't appear deprecated to me. `reload()` replaced `revision()` if that is what you're looking for. I don't understand "I think so to need create method reload() or revision(), that is deprecated."

Comment: @Ronnie Just I dont know how create this method reload() or revision()